# How to avoid opening the worddocument which is already open?

Tags: c#, .net

In my scenario I am opening Word documents melodramatically. If the programm opens the same document it should prompt the user that the document is already opened.

```
Process[] pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
if (pro.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (Process p in pro)
    {
       p.kill(); 
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to find the process and killing already opened documents. The problem is that it is killing word.exe so that all the other opened documents also close.

How do I find the name of the document and close that particular document only?

I used `p.MainWindowTitle` to get the opened document's name but its not showing all the opened documents, rather showing the first opened document name.

What is the correct solution?

Comment: Get rid of that IF, its ridiculous. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `File.Open` method to open the file in non-sharing mode `FileShare.None`.

```
FileStream stream = null;
bool isOpen = false;
try
{
   stream = File.Open(@"DFilePath&Name",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
}
catch(IOException)
{
  isOpen = true;
  //Show your prompt here.
}
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
        stream.Close();
}
if(!isOpen)    
  Process.Start(@"FilePath&Name");
```

If the file is already open, it will throw an `IOException` which you can catch and show your prompt.

BTW why were you killing all the processes in the first place if all you had to do was to show a prompt?

Comment: How does this get the file into word, if it's opened in `FileShare.None`?

Comment: @Matt OP wants to know how to check if the file is already in use before opening it. This code just that. If you want to open the word doc, use `Process.Start`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

*This is a general solution direction.*

- you need to add the reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
- I think Word Interop makes you specify even the default arguments. That's tedious but it is way less tedious than getting the window title and a lot more robust, if you ask me

Use [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=Office.11%29.aspx):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Open a doc file.
        Application application = new Application();
        Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

        // Close word. if desired
        // application.Quit();
    }
}
```

I suspect word will automatically prevent opening the same document twice. If not, the Documetns interface to enumerate any currently opened documents, so you can check beforehand

Comment: Why are you looping through all the words?!!

Comment: Ok I'll remove less relevant bits from sample. I sort of gather that people will see what they need; the rest of the sample was to draw attention this API is not just any 'File Launcher' or something

Comment: I still fail to understand how this will "enumerate any currently opened documents". Moreover you usage of the API `application.Documents.Open` is also not correct. Please edit your answer so that it is helpful to OP.

Comment: @Mayank: no need to get angry because _you can't get it working in 5 minutes_. I updated the answer. (By the way, I did _not say_ that this snippet will enumerate anything. You can use the same API to do that, yes)

Comment: @sehe We are all here to help, not get angry. :) It would be useful if you could post the code which actually enumerates the opened docs (as you have written in your answer) and remove the existing one as it is confusing.

Comment: I know it would be helpful. But as you said: we're here to help, I'm not some evil villain sitting on 'your' code but not showing it. I don't have the time. This pointer should get the OP going. (I already edited the sample down, and confusing is a very subjective matter. Keep in mind that versions of Word Interop might make a difference there)

Comment: Hi friends i didnt get what i exaclty want... am sorry if am not clearly explained the problem ..consider i have opened three word documents say test.doc,test1.doc,test2.doc (programatically using C#) now clicking on a button am again opening test.doc .. here i should kill the process of test.doc and other document should not affected ...is that is possible...

Comment: You can supply the 'revert' flag on the interop API to have the desired effect. I might find some time to wip up this code, but (a) it won't be today (b) it is not my favourite sibject: I don't use windows anymore