# Get the word file write protection attribute

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

In case when a word document is opened over the network, and another user is editing it, the file is write blocked for other users. A small window pops up with possibility to open the file write protected, create a local copy and to merge the files later or to notify when the file is available again.

I would like to read out that flag before opening the document. Unfortunately it is not the file property flag (FileInfo), which is set using file system.  How is it possible to get the "already in use" flag using .Net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid opening the worddocument which is already open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700973/how-to-avoid-opening-the-worddocument-which-is-already-open)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use but no free lunch

Comment: wow, thank you very much,  I though it is only applicable on local pc. it works, thx :)